# The ChromeDriver could not be found on the current PATH

Tags: automated-testing, chromedriver, selenium-ide, nodejs

I wrote a test suite for a web application by using Selenium IDE and I used ChromeDriver to test the application, the code I used is as followed.

`C:\>set APPLITOOLS_API_KEY=OYpD2zINOUyFkxUL9Go7CeLX3rn7K6ihVvXdaQrPBzE110 && selenium-side-runner C:\Users\user\Downloads\the-internet-july.side`

The test is getting fail and it shows this error every time. I installed ChromeDriver 91.0.4472.101 related to the Chrome version 91.0.4472.124. I run `npm audit fix` but that doesn't work to solve that.
So that how can I find the path for the ChromeDriver and how can I fix and continue this test?

[image]

Comment: The downloaded Chromedriver file has to be in PATH. So you either put the .exe file to a folder that's already in PATH, or you add a new folder with the Chromedriver to PATH. https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/

Comment: I set up the PATH but in the execution when chrome windows opened and it didn't visible any process and this error is shown after.`Request failed with status code 401(Unauthorized) (Use node --trace-warnings ...to show where the warning was created) (node:3224) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Caught error after test environment was torn down`

Comment: Ok, so the Chrome problem is solved. Now you need to find out why you're getting 401 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401 and how to authorize.

Comment: I referred to your document but was unable to come up with a solution. Can you explain the reason for that error?

Comment: is that .exe file located in an accessible directory or folder?